# List of all columns for given data types

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to groupby datatypes in pandas?
For e.g. I need a list of all columns of "objects" or "float" types.

This code will return exactly what I need. I am looking for a better way to achive this (if possible).

```
from collections import defaultdict
food_count = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in dict(df.dtypes).items():
    food_count[v].append(i)

dict(food_count)

{dtype('<M8[ns]'): ['agency_spot_time'],
 dtype('int64'): ['cost', 'spot_id', 'Event'],
 dtype('O'): ['channel'],
 dtype('float64'): ['viziters']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
food_count = (lambda s: (
     pd.Series(s.index, s).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()))(df.dtypes)
```

A more readable version of this is:

```
s = df.dtypes
food_count = pd.Series(s.index, s).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict())
```